# Is it time to give up the [ghost]?

Tags: discussion, burnination

There are currently 66 questions tagged with [[ghost]](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ghost?sort=newest&pageSize=50), and they are really inconsistently used. We have:

- Story identification 30
- *Harry Potter* 22
- “Force ghosts” in *Star Wars* 3
- Mythology 2
- *Doctor Who* 1
- *Deadbeat* 1
- *The Crucible* 1
- A creepypasta (story identification?) 1
- *Supernatural* 1
- Portrayal of ghosts in film 1
- *Drag Me to Hell* 1
- Combination of the *Merlin* TV series, *Supernatural*, and mythology 1
- The 1990 movie *Ghost* (starring Patrick Swayze) 1

By my count, that's 9 franchises this covers, plus story identification, mythology, and production history. The ghosts in all of these vary wildly in what sort of rules they follow, and I find it hard to imagine someone finding value in grouping together *Harry Potter*, *Deadbeat*, and a Patrick Swayze movie. Is it time for this tag to [give up the ghost](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/give+up+the+ghost)?

Comment: We have a special [tag:force-ghost] tag, so I retagged those 3.

Comment: How is it unfocused? I guess the tag is for stuff about ghosts. No way of telling from what you posted, how many of those 66 questions are not about ghosts. By the way, -1 because I'm tired of cute titles.

Comment: "I have no wish to do the ghost any personal injury. Considering the time he has been in the house I dont think it is at all polite to throw pillows at him."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## NO, let it *live*!

I disagree with the inconsistent use. The tag is not covering franchises, it is covering a creature. We also have tags for [zombie](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zombie), [vampire](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vampire), and [werewolf](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/werewolf), which would fall into the same category.

- About half of the tags are used for [story-id](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-id) questions, which when trying to identify a story about ghosts, would be pretty useful.
- The other majority is used by Harry Potter which has a bit of a theme with death and therefore ghosts. It would be proper to use this tag when asking questions inline with the story.
- The remaining 8-10 questions might be a bit random, but if about ghosts are probably using the tag properly.
- The only one that might need a re-tag is the one about the Swayze movie. It could use something like [movie-year](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/movie-year) format.

Answer (score 1):

### Yes, delete it

While the tag does seem to be accurately tagging questions about ghosts, it's so overly broad that it is useless. Ghosts in *Harry Potter* have little in common with ghosts in *Doctor Who* or *Deadbeat*, for instance, aside from the fact that they both share the same name. They follow different rules, have different origins, and otherwise are quite different beings.  We don't have tags for [science](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science) or [military](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/military) because they are so broad, and I think that [ghost](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ghost) is approaching this too.

Also, I find it hard to imagine that someone would be an expert in ghosts from the 9 franchises currently covered, or want to group all those questions together. At best, this has value as a sub-tag of interest for *Harry Potter*, but that's not what the tag wiki describes.

What about story identification questions? I think we can live without it, since many such questions don't have a secondary tag, and I'm pretty confident that these ones would have been answerd if they lacked the [ghost](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ghost) tag.

Comment: Would you also recommend that the zombie and vampire tags be removed as well then?

Comment: @Skooba Now that I am aware they exist, yes I would. Dracula vampires and Twilight vampires have little in common.